# How do I scan BOM In php file names while doing a directory search?

Tags: php, byte-order-mark

How do I scan Byte Order Marks In PHP file names while doing a directory search?

I have about 220 php files with a BOM added to the beginning of the file name.
%EF%BB%B

They look like this:
https://www.dme.net/Pages/%EF%BB%BPLATE-PULLER-.php
https://www.dme.net/Pages/%EF%BB%BPOLYCARBONATE-LOCATING-RINGS.php

These look unprofessional.

To fix this I tried to scan the directory, then remove the BOM, "%EF%BB%B".
As it turned out my php search cannot see the BOM, "%EF%BB%B".

It only sees https://www.dme.net/Pages/POLYCARBONATE-LOCATING-RINGS.php when scanning https://www.dme.net/Pages/%EF%BB%BPOLYCARBONATE-LOCATING-RINGS.php.

"%EF%BB%B" is invisible to my searches.

Here is a code sample.

```
 <?php 
                $directory = getcwd();
                $directory = $directory."/";
                $phpfiles = scandir($directory);
                
                foreach($phpfiles as $phpfile) 
                {
                    echo "<p>phpfile is ".$phpfile."</p>";
                    if($phpfile != "/RenameBadFiles10.php")
                    {
                          echo "<p>".$phpfile."</p>";
                          echo "<br>";
                          $new_name = str_replace("%EF%BB%B","",$phpfile);
                          
                          $FullOldFileName = $directory."".$phpfile;
                          $FullNewFileName = $directory."".$new_name;
                        
                        // using rename() function to rename the file
                        rename($FullOldFileName, $FullNewFileName);
                
                        echo $FullOldFileName." renamed to ".$FullNewFileName;
                    }
                }
    ?>
```

How can I detect and remove the %EF%BB%B in file names when doing directory searches with PHP?

Comment: You can always use [`rawurlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) to convert it into your URL encoded version (`%EF%BB%B`) and then use [`rawurldecode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) to convert it back into your new filename.

Comment: Also the BOM is `xEFxBBxBF` and `%B` alone is simply invalid.